# Change KAPT class generation path

Tags: gradle, kotlin, annotations, annotation-processing, kapt

I want to instruct my Kotlin annotation processor to change the output directory of the generated classes.

I want from my Gradle build script to change the `kapt.kotlin.generated` argument. I have tried the following to no avail.

1. Doesn't work, path doesn't change

   `kapt {
       arguments {
           arg("kapt.kotlin.generated", new File('path'))
       }
    }`
2. Doesn't work, path doesn't change

   `kapt {
       javacOptions {
           option("kapt.kotlin.generated", new File('path'))
       }
    }`
3. Doesn't work, NullPointerException when building

   `kapt {
       javacOptions {
           option("-Akapt.kotlin.generated", new File('path'))
       }
    }`

Same results for all three when using a string path instead of a file.

I am at a loss, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use a different option name:

```
kapt{
    arguments {
        arg("kapt.kotlin.custom.generated",
                rootProject.file("foobar/build/generated/source/kaptKotlin/main").absolutePath)
    }
}
```

then retrieve the custom option in your annotation processor and use that as the target